# Не возможно вызвать функцию FindAllFiles

Tags: lazarus

В Lazarus есть функция поиска всех файлов по маске в заданном каталоге. Называется FindAllFiles. Описана она в официальном модуле LazFileUtils. Однако, воспользоваться ей не представляется возможным еще на этапе подключения соответствующего пакета и попытки скомпилировать программу. Ошибка возникает в функции GetCurrentDirUtf8.

Приложение консольное. Способы решения, которые находил не помогли. Вроде подключения пакета LCL.

В чем здесь проблема?

[image: Место ошибки]

[image: Описание ошибки]